# Git bash win32exception: Failed to write credentials

Tags: eclipse, git, bash, github, win32exception

I've recently started using GitHub but for some reason every time I attempt to pull or push it asks for my credentials. I'm 100% sure I have my credentials correct but git bash keeps giving this error:

```
fatal: Win32Exception encountered.
       Failed to write credentials
```

I don't know why but it does work every time I reinstall git bash up until my next reboot.

Please ask for any information you might need because I'm still quite unfamiliar with git.

Answer (score 3):

Check if you have set a [credential helper](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials) with `git config -l|grep credential`

On Windows, you should make sure you have:

```
git config --global credential.helper manager
```

With recent [Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases), that does use the [Microsoft Git Credential Manager](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows), linked to the [Credential Manager in Windows](https://blog.malwarebytes.com/101/2016/01/the-windows-vaults/).

Comment: First off thanks for your time, I get the following 2 pop-ups to log in. in this order: https://gyazo.com/e6709105c99b8fc4d0b0d836693aeae9 https://gyazo.com/01f6ba742e56f174cb381e0cd1e12c6c

Comment: I'm unsure, but I think this is because your credentials are a proxy of some sort and not the real credentials.  Your real user probably dosesn't have permissions to write to the Credential Manager